# Find correlation between vectors with continuous and binary vectors in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have two matrices. The first contains continuous variables for each of the 6 cells.

```
mat1.data <- c(-0.12, -0.09, -0.01, -0.2,  0.3,  0.1, 
               0.2, -0.5, -0.1,  0.7, -0.04, 0.02, -0.08,
               -0.2, -0.7, -0.26, -0.09, -0.04, 0.05,  0.01,
               -0.26, -0.36, -0.26, -0.05, -0.03, 0.02, -0.01,
               0.01, 0.01, -0.05)
mat1 <- matrix(mat1.data,nrow=6,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(mat1) <- paste0("cell", seq(1,6,1))
colnames(mat1) <- paste0("col", seq(1,5,1))
```

the second matrix has binary values

```
mat2.data <- c(0,1,0,0,0,
               1,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,1,0,0,
               0,0,0,1,0,
               1,0,0,0,0,
               0,0,0,0,1)
mat2 <- matrix(mat2.data,nrow=6,ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
rownames(mat2) <- paste0("cell", seq(1,6,1))
colnames(mat2) <- paste0("var", seq(1,5,1))
```

How do I get correlation between cols from mat1 and vars from mat2?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the effect of `cor(mat1[,1], mat2[,1])` and such for each column, then

```r
Map(cor, asplit(mat1, 2), asplit(mat2, 2))
# $col1
# [1] 0.06984303
# $col2
# [1] -0.0934997
# $col3
# [1] 0.1646495
# $col4
# [1] 0.6145488
# $col5
# [1] -0.09377887
```

Use `mapply` instead of `Map` to get a simple vector.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you can simply use `cor`

```
> cor(mat1, mat2)
            var1        var2       var3        var4        var5
col1  0.06984303 -0.08834522  0.1766904 -0.55215763  0.37546719
col2 -0.10559715 -0.09349970  0.2003565 -0.09349970  0.12021390
col3 -0.91116795  0.33753145  0.1646495  0.26343918  0.38692630
col4  0.04919934 -0.55231599 -0.5523160  0.61454877  0.42785041
col5  0.49798831  0.27779780 -0.7838498 -0.03008002 -0.09377887
```

or if you are just interested in correlation of corresponding columns

```
> diag(cor(mat1,mat2))
[1]  0.06984303 -0.09349970  0.16464949  0.61454877 -0.09377887
```